# Entity Framework ignores Include on a Grand Child

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

My models structure looks like this:

```
UserProgresses:dbset
    LessonProgresses:List  // The lesson progress a user has in one course
        Lesson:Lesson      // The general Lesson class. 
            Materials:List // A list of lesson materials
```

When I execute this query:

```
 var progresses = context.UserProgresses
.Include(x => x.LessonProgresses.Select(y => y.Lesson.Materials))
.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == progressId);
```

This is the result I get after executing that query:

```
foreach (var lessonProgress in  progress.LessonProgress)
{
     lessonProgress.Lesson // Works
     lessonProgress.Lesson.Materials // NULL
}
```

The interesting thing here is that when I insert the row below inside the loop and on the first line the `Materials` list gets populated.

```
context.Lessons.Include(x => x.Material)
  .SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == lesson.Lesson.Id);
```

I also checked the tables and the data is OK. I suspect that something is wrong with the `Include` statement.

Thanks.

Comment: Tried in simple console project, EF6.1.3, SqlServer db and it's working as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem was that the `LessonProgress` was untracked and was added way back in the callstack. The `Lesson` was set using:

```
lessonProgress.Lesson = context.Lessons.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == lessonId);
```

Without including Materials. After doing a `Include` there, everything was all good.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use a string to specify the relationships

```
var progresses = context.UserProgresses
.Include("LessonProgresses.Lesson.Materials")
.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == progressId);
```

[MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx#eagerLevels)

Or try this

```
var progresses = context.UserProgresses
.Include(u => u.LessonProgress.Select(l => l.Lesson).Select(m => m.Materials))
.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == progressId);
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have posted all my tried. I tried the last one as well which resulted in null.
I can't think of any more ways to include. Seperating the query works and showed in my last code snippet, however that is not an ideal soloution for us.

Comment: I have created entity models just like yours and everything works fine. I have no idea what could be wrong in your code. Models: http://snag.gy/jSzbq.jpg  Debug: http://snag.gy/PQyHB.jpg

Comment: Could it be something with: LessonProgress is NOT tracked by EF, however Lesson is.